# How to duplicate repeat items inside a dart list?

Tags: flutter, dart

My intention is that i want say  5 instances of an class inside a list

```
final List<Ball> _ballList =[Ball(),Ball(),Ball(),Ball(),Ball(),]
```

instead of that I want something like

```
final List<Ball> _ballList =[Ball() * 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `generate()` should help

For example,

```
class Ball{
  String color;
}

void main() {
  List<Ball> ballList = new List<Ball>.generate(5,(i)=>Ball());
  for(int i=0;i<ballList.length;i++) {
    print(ballList[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With Dart 2.3 or later, you could use [collection-`for`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators):

```dart
final List<Ball> _ballList = [
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) Ball(),
];
```

Note that the above will generate a `List` with 5 *different* instances of `Ball`, which I'm *assuming* is what you want.  In languages (e.g. Python) that support constructs like your `[Ball() * 5]` example, you'd instead get a list that contains 5 elements of the *same instance*.  If want the same instance instead, then you could use the [`List.filled` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/List/List.filled.html):

```dart
final List<Ball> _ballList = List<Ball>.filled(5, Ball());
```